# Getting the departure time based on a desired arrival time for driving

Tags: google-maps-api, distance-matrix

**Context:**
I'm working on a logical problem as part of my Msc. thesis in GIS. I want to calculate the departure time (output) based on a desired arrival time (input). I have chosen to use an API to outsource much of the coding and maintenance.

**Current Problem:**
Tried to use the [Google Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) and [Google Diretions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) API's. Both do not allow a travel mode of driving combined with an arrival time as input.

**Question:**
What API can be used with the (batch size 1 - 50) input of a desired arrival time (/datetime) and a transport mode of driving to give an estimated departure time/travel duration taking into account traffic conditions such as rush-hour?

**Related Posts:**

[API - Travel time based on arrival time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707375/api-travel-time-based-on-arrival-time) | No clear answer is given here

[Google Maps Directions API - Arrival time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617631/google-maps-dircetions-api-arrival-time) | 2500+ views on stackoverflow since 2.5 years, no clear answer yet. One of the comments mentions the HERE API, but [their documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html) suggests it is not possible. See the note in the below picture.

After Taras Comment: [Looking for free web service that calculates driving distance between 2 addresses](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15199/looking-for-free-web-service-that-calculates-driving-distance-between-2-addresse) | Question is about driving time, not driving time based on desired arrival time per se. Bing maps, google maps, HERE maps, and arcgis are recommended. As far as I have been able to find, these do not allow for specifying the 'desired arrival time' (except for public transport).

[REST calculateroute want to supply arrival time to determine when to depart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826511/rest-calculateroute-want-to-supply-arrival-time-to-determine-when-to-depart) | Question from 2012 about the same problem, but specific for the HERE maps API. Answered on 4 oct 2018 (6 year later?) that only public transport modality is supported for now.

[image]

Comment: PGRouting should be able to do that, can you install software?

Comment: Yes, I thought about PGRouting, but that would make the eventual application maintenance intensive compared to when the routing is done exclusively via an API. Therefore my preference would be to solve the problem via an API. Also, building a network in PostGIS that has different characteristics through time (in/outside rush hour) would be quite a lot of work.

Comment: Are you interested in fees-free solutions or you can consider commercial offers as well? Have you checked [TravelTime Search API](http://docs.traveltimeplatform.com/overview/introduction) it provides with a full coverage for Netherlands; [Travel Time API](https://localyse.eu/travel-time-api-2/); [The Mapfruition Travel Time API](https://market.mashape.com/mapfruition/travel-time)?

Comment: There is also a related topic [Looking for free web service that calculates driving distance between 2 addresses](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15199/looking-for-free-web-service-that-calculates-driving-distance-between-2-addresse).

Comment: @Taras, a paid solution is OK. Thanks for the links. Currently investigating Bing maps distance matrix.

Comment: I haven't tested it but arrival time is listed as an option for the [Get Route HERE Rest API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-get-route.html). It looks like you would have to calculate the route first without the arrival time and then get the travel time.  This would mean the route is not optimised for the traffic but the travel time would take into account the past or future traffic.

Answer (score 0):

using the travelTime platform's api you can do 'arrival_searches'- which let you 'arrive at a destination no later than a given time' - it takes the the mode of transport, start and end points as input

since it returns a travel_time property, calculating the departure time would simply be subtracting the travel time from your arrival time

it appears that you can specify upto 10 searches at a time, but if you have 50 you want to process (i'm assuming this is what you mean by batch) , you could submit several requests

api documentation here:

http://docs.traveltimeplatform.com/reference/routes/

Comment: This indeed looks more like it. Although your answer showed me that I left out a crucial bit of information in my question (which i just eddited), the routing has to account for predicted traffic conditions such as rush hour. It seems like the travelTime platform does not account for traffic conditions (at least is not excplicitly stated on their site)

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox’s directions API allows you to specify arrival time and accounts for historical traffic conditions. As suggested above you can then work backwards from the arrival time and estimated trip length to get the suggested departure.

https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/directions/